# Input type=text not passing values with some values

Tags: php, html, post

I am having a problem using an html/php app.

I have a form with an `input type="text" name="email"` tag. In this tag, if I submit my e-mail xxxxxxx@xxxx.com I get the value with no problems at `$_POST['email']`.

If the value passed is something like xxxx.xxxx@xxxx.com the value is not passed neither `$_POST['email']` is defined.

Has someone experienced a problem like that?

So, I am posting here my code.

After the submit of the form I am doing a print_r of the $_POST value.

When it works, it returns

```
Array
(
[email] => teste@example.com
[recuperar] => Recuperar
)
```

The form is:

```
<form action="example.com/recuperar-palavra-passe.html" method="post" id="registo" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
   <tr>
    <td><label for="user_email"><? echo __('Digite o seu e-mail'); ?>:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email'] ?>" id="user_email" class="regi"> </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Sometimes, and with that email I get:

```
Array
(
)
```

Even the value email is not defined

Comment: did you set enctype="multipart/form-data" for the form element?

Comment: Post your code, for more detail

Comment: Could you post your code, cause it works fine for me.

Comment: are you sure you're using post not get

Comment: `<input type="email">` is your friend, btw.

Comment: @peku33 That's completely irrelevant, you shouldn't suggest solutions that you don't understand.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` could shed some light. If nothing in there, `var_dump($_SERVER)` and just search there for the data you've submitted. It could be the $_POST is being written to somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me, even with xxx.xxx@xxx.com

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo $_POST['email'];
        }
    ?>

    <form action='index.php' method='post'>
        <input type=text name ='email'>
        <input type=submit name=submit value=submit>
    </form>
```